# Save output from nested for loop: random movement of particles over many time steps

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm new to MATLAB, and trying to simulate some random particle movement.

I want to

- Start my particles at depth = 0,
- Then at each time step, move them by (swimming speed)*(random number) to represent random variation in swimming speeds.
- Then I want to change the depth of each particle by adding its randomised swimming speed for that time step to its original depth.
- Finally I want to create an array to display the depths of each particle at each time step.

I'm trying to save the output from a nested for loop as an array to achieve this but it isn't currently working. My code is written below

```
nT = 200 %number of timesteps
N = 50 %particles
w = 0.05 %swimming speed

d = zeros(1,N)
for i = 1:N
    d(i) = 0
end

for ts = 1:nT
    for i = 1:N
         r(i) = rand
         d_new(i) = d(i) + w*rand
         d(i) = d_new(i)
    end
end
```

I would like to create a 200*50 array containing the values of `d` for each particle, for each time step.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your 'd' is all zeros....is that what you want? And what are you needing r(i) = rand for, what is the goal of that piece?

Comment: im trying to  start my particles at depth =0, then move them by swimming speed*random number to represent random variation in swimming speeds.  then i want to change the depth of each particle by adding its randomised swimming speed for that timestep to its original depth.  finally i want to create an array to display the depths of each particle at each timetsep. does that make more sense?

Comment: Is there a range that you need for your random number?

Comment: @Wolfie , "`d_new(i)`, which is always equal to `w*rand` anyway because `d(i)=0` always", `d(i)` isn't always equal to `0`, after the first iteration, `d(i) = d_new(i)`

Comment: just noticed why everyones getting confused about the random bit!! its meant to read d_new(i) = d(i) + w*r(i)

Comment: @MollyJ So are your particles just moving downward?... just in one direction? Otherwise, I don't think you have enough info here to move the particle in the x and y direction.

Comment: @Flynn yes just one direction... like i said i'm new. I'm going with a start at the bottom, build an understanding and work my way up approach... this is where i've got to thus far

Comment: Hi Molly, I've tried to break down what you're trying to do, and shown you some best practises as you're only starting out. I hope my answer is informative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, some MATLAB basics. You don't usually need to loop through all elements in an array, for instance

```
N = 50 
d = zeros(1,N); % You've created an array of zeros, 1 row by N columns
% You don't need the following loop, as that goes over each element
% in 'd' and sets it equal to 0 - something we've already done. 
%  for i = 1:N
%     d(i) = 0;
%  end
```

This will also apply when you're altering the depth value for each particle. Below I show you can get rid of the inner `for` loop in favour of "vectorized" code - this is something to get to grips with when writing in MATLAB.

---

Okay, so let's break down what you want to do, based on how you've described it.

- **"I'm trying to start my particles at depth = 0"** 
   Brilliant, we've already done this with `d = zeros(1,N);`. What would be better would be to create a row for every time step. That way we are saving as we go through the time loop

  ```
  nT = 200  % Number of time steps
  N  = 50   % Number of particles
  d  = zeros(nT, N); % Matrix of zeros, row per timestep, column per particle
  ```

  By setting up the entire array to begin with, we are being kinder on the computer's memory, which will (usually) be quicker and is best practise.
- **"Then move them by (swimming speed)*(random number) to represent random variation in swimming speeds"**. Also adding these randomised speeds and storing them in an array. This part can all be achieved as follows:

  ```
  % Set up initial variables
  w = 0.05 % Swimming speed

  % Set up some time loop. Start from row 2, as row 1 is our initial conditions
  for t = 2:nT
      % Create a random value for each particle at once
      r = rand(1,N);
      % Apply random movement to the particles, store in next time step
      % We access row 't', all columns using d(t,:)
      d(t,:) = d(t-1,:) + w*r;
  end
  ```

---

**So the entire code**, with only key comments (to show how compact it is) would be:

```
% Set up parameters
nT = 200; N = 50; w = 0.05;
% Set up results matrix, including initial conditions by row 1 (all 0)
d = zeros(nT, N);
% Loop, storing results to d
for t = 2:nT
    d(t,:) = d(t-1,:) + w*rand(1,N);
end
```

Comment: thankyou for this! i'll have a play around with it now and see if i can get in the practice of being less convoluted

Comment: No problem, it's just about learning how to access arrays mainly. For instance, if you extended this to 2D, you may want to store your results in a 3D matrix and you can learn how to address elements in that too (hint, it's going to be something like `d(t,:,:)`!). You're also going to want to look up "element-wise operations". Feel free to swap your "accepted" mark if you found this more useful, completely up to you.

Answer (score -2):

You can add

```
d_new_value(ts, i) = d(i)
```

after

```
d_new(i) = d(i) + w*rand
d(i) = d_new(i)
```

In this case, after both `for`, `d_new_value` wil be a 200x50 matrix.

Or you can do

```
d_new_value = [];
for ts = 1:nT
    for i = 1:N
         r(i) = rand
         d_new(i) = d(i) + w*rand
         d(i) = d_new(i)
    end
    d_new_value = [d_new_value; d];
end
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: I saw a mistake in the first line, I hope that's why you asking me this @beaker . but no i haven't test this yet

Comment: I just tested this and it did work, I have a 200*50 random value. But if there is a problem I think it's a comprehension problem